# executing long running hive queries from remote machine

Tags: python, hadoop, ssh, hive, paramiko

I've to execute long running (~10 hours) hive queries from my local server using a python script. my target hive server is in an aws cluster.

I've tried to execute it using 
pyhs2, execute('`<command>`')

and

paramiko, exec_command('hive -e "`<command>`"')

in both cases my query will be running in hive server and will complete successfully. but issue is even after successfully completing the query my parent python script continue to wait for return value and will remain in Interruptible sleep (Sl) state for infinite time!

is there anyway I can make my script work fine using pyhs2 or paramiko? os is there any other better option available in python?

Comment: I don't know `pyhs2` but with `paramiko`, the function `exec_command()` would return immediately so I don't understand what you mean by *continue to wait for return value*.

Comment: Even i am facing similar issue with pyhs2 and pyhive libraries, Any suggestions or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned before that even I face a similar issue in my Performance based environment.
My use-case was i was using PYHS2 module to run queries using HIVE TEZ execution engine. TEZ generates lot of logs(basically in seconds scale). the logs gets captured in STDOUT variable and is provided to the output once the query successfully completes.
The way to overcome is to stream the output as an when it is generated as shown below:

```
    for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(2048), ""):
    print line
```

But for this you will have to use native connection to cluster using PARAMIKO or FABRIC and then issue hive command via CLI or beeline.